# Why is javascript triggered click event inside a loop not updating state every time in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a checkbox and a button.

When I click the **checkbox**, `count` is updated using `setCount` and incremented by  `1`.

When I click the **button**, I want to click the `checkbox` 10 times.

So, `setCount` should update `count` value **10 times** and final value of `count` should be **10**.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("count updated to :", count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        id="start"
        onClick={(e) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.getElementById("check").click();
          }
        }}
      >
        start
      </button>
      <input
        id="check"
        type="checkbox"
        value={count}
        onClick={(e) => setCount(count + 1)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the problem is when I click the button, count only increased by **1**. I'm sure its related to **asynchronicity** of React Hooks.

How to make the checkbox click and update the state properly 10 times?

Comment: why do you want to click the checkbox 10 times? why not just set the count to 10 when you click the button?

Comment: if you do `document.getElementById("check").click()` instead of `<button onClick={....}>` why are you using react

Comment: I agree with @punjira's solution.  Seems redundant to click the checkbox 10 times when you could just simply increment your value +10

Comment: @Michael Increasing by `10` doesn't solve the problem. It was just an example to simplify. Real problem is there are many checkboxes. Every checkbox has its own state. So when I press start button, it should click all checkboxes and not just that, onClick event of all checkboxes should fire, because they all perform different computation.

Comment: @SauravPathak I would recommend updating your question since you are specifically asking how to update state of the ONE checkbox 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to access DOM elements directly when using react. I can't see why this might not solve your problem:

```
 <button
    id="start"
    onClick={(e) => {
       setCount(pc=>pc+10)
    }}
 >
```

and if you need to see the click event you can always perform some async action that increments the count value over some sort of timeout.
But if you really need to perform a click event on your check box use can use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Increasing by `10` doesn't solve the problem. It was just an example to simplify. Real problem is there are many checkboxes. Every checkbox has its own state. So when I press start button, it should click all checkboxes and not just that, onClick event of all checkboxes should fire, because they all perform different computation. @punjira

Comment: @SauravPathak, you should come up with a solution to meet your requirements by using state and controlled inputs. firing events like that is anti-pattern and by going around the whole lifecycle of react , can easily cause messy side-effects.

Comment: didn't know it was considered as an anti-pattern. I'm only starting out with react so. I have found solution using state only. Thanks.